# Make `?` of an reexported function refer to the original function

Tags: r, roxygen2

Suppose I want to have `%>%` from magrittr available to users of my package. I know I can create a file in `./R/` like the following to achieve this.

```r
#' @importFrom magrittr %>%
#' @export
"%>%" <- magrittr::`%>%`
```

However, this technique has the downside that `?'%>%'` is not resolved to magrittr's help page, even if `magrittr` is attached; instead, it opens an intermediate page:

> Help on topic '%>%' was found in the following packages:

or a help file that links to magrittr's help file.

How can I ensure `?"%>%"` points directly to magrittr's topic page? Or in general how can I reexport a function from a package while ensuring documentation shortcuts are resolved to the correct help file?

Comment: The devtools folks recommend using `usethis::use_pipe()` to bring  the pipe operator into your package. It uses [this template](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/blob/master/inst/templates/pipe.R). Basically they just stub in a help page pointing to the magrittr documentation. I'm not sure you can have `?` open directly to the documentation for another (possibly unloaded) package.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that doesn't quite do: there's still an extra step to get to the real documentation. Since I'm importing the function I can assume the original function's package (`magrittr` in this example) will be loaded.